# What's the best way to keep queries ?

Tags: django

i'm poor with django.

i have a project and project has an app

in my app, i have a models.py and includes

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = TaggableManager()    


    def __unicode__(self):
     return self.title
```

and i also add this models.py

posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")[:2]

Is it the right way to keep it here?

Some examples shows that queries in models.py some are in views.py ?

Also can i use posts in my mysite/templates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to [create a custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) with a method that performs the query when called. That way you don't need to worry about it being cached, recycled, etc.

Comment: when i created a custom manager, how can i send return statement to my template ?

Comment: ... I don't even understand what that question is asking.

Comment: what i mean is that where i have to put querysets in django ? view.py or models.py?

Comment: Query sets aren't "put" anywhere; they're returned by functions that return query sets.

Comment: oke i understood what they are . I created model Post as you see. How can i retrieve datas datas ? Do i have to put query in that model and how can i send it to my template?